# How to make a command block activate by reaching a specific coordinate in Minecraft 1.20.1

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

For example, if you are in -52 -60 35 and if you go to -52 -60 50 you get sent back to -52 -60 35.

I tried this:

```
/execute if entity @p[distance:..5] run tp @p -52 -60 35
```

How can you make a command block activate by reaching a specific coordinate?

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea! A simple way to accomplish this would be to target players based on their distance to the command block, which was also attempted in the example you provided. Here's a command that you can adapt to your needs:

```
execute as @a[gamemode=survival, distance=..5] run tp @s -52 -60 35
```

This teleports Survival players to `-52 -60 35` if they get within 5 blocks of the command block (which should be a Repeating Command Block). Let's go through each part of the command.

1. **`execute as @a[...] run`** This tries to find any players that match the target selector (explained below), and runs the rest of the command with `@s` set to the player that matched it

   1. **`gamemode=survival`** This limits it to players in Survival mode, to stop you from being teleported around while you're working on the map.
   2. **`distance=..5`** This limits it to players that are less than 5 blocks away from the command block. Your original command had a syntax error at this point: you need to use `=` (not `:`) when setting target selector arguments.
2. **`run tp @s -52 -60 35`** This runs the `tp` command to teleport the player back. We use `@s` to ensure that we teleport the player matched by the previous selector.

Minecraft commands can be confusing at times, but don't give up - you'll gain more and more understanding as you progress. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Try this: `/execute positioned ~ ~ ~ run`...
Replace `~ ~ ~`  with the x y z coordinates of your target block.

Comment: Btw. for what you need it?